# getting orderID and then using that for inserting in order items (Create order function)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have seen below code on the net that use below technique for inserting order and order items in one time.

```
  Models.ShopDBEntities db = new ShopDBEntities();

   public IEnumerable<Basket> GetList()
    {
        return db.Baskets.Where(x => x.UserName == UserName);
    }

  public void CreateOrder(Models.Order order)
    {
        foreach (var b in GetList())
        {
            OrderItem oi = new OrderItem()
            {
                Price = b.Product.Price,
                ProductID = b.ProductID
            };
            order.OrderItems.Add(oi);
        }
        db.Orders.Add(order);
        db.SaveChanges();

        ClearBasket();
    }
```

understanding this for me is a bit difficult. i understand for inserting records in order items,before we must have orderID. now i am looking for another way that is more understandable and shows step by step CreateOrder function.

1- first inserting records in orders table and save that.

2- then get orderID of inserted order and use that for inserting and saving in order items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand for inserting records in order items, [first] we must have orderID

No. The database does, but Entity Framework handles that for you transparently.

The code you show adds the order item lines to the order, and then inserts the order as well as the order item lines in one transaction.

It does so by first inserting the order, obtaining the auto-generated primary key and using that in the insertion of the order item lines.

This happens because Entity Framework sees that the OrderItems added to the context are the same OrderItems that the added Order contains, by object reference.

In fact, because Entity Framework is an ORM that should hide the relative complexity of your database schema, the order items don't even need to have an `OrderId` property exposed: the entity that contains them gives Entity Framework enough information to work with.

If you *do* want to see what happens in separate steps, it would look like this to save the order:

```
var order = new Order
{
    Description = "Example order"
};

db.Orders.Add(order);   
db.SaveChanges();
```

Now after `SaveChanges()` the `order.Id` property is assigned with the primary key, which you can use to add order item lines:

```
var orderItem1 = new OrderItem
{
    OrderId = order.Id,
    Description = "Order 1 Item 1"
};
var orderItem2 = new OrderItem
{
    OrderId = order.Id,
    Description = "Order 1 Item 2"
};
var orderItem3 = new OrderItem
{
    OrderId = order.Id,
    Description = "Order 1 Item 3"
};

db.OrderItems.Add(orderItem1);
db.OrderItems.Add(orderItem2);
db.OrderItems.Add(orderItem3);
db.SaveChanges();
```